# Как настроить TailwindCss в Nx Angular Microfrontends Apps?

Tags: angular, tailwindcss, nx

Я создал микрофронтенды на ангуляр в монорепозитории NX.
Подключил TailwindCss, но Tailwindcss работает только  если я смотрю отдельно приложение микрофронтенда, а если смотрю через хост на стандартном порту, то Tailwind не работает.

ПОдскажите, что нужно ещё настроить?
Спасибо.